# Como mostra o valor de uma var dentro de uma span html java

Tags: javascript, html

Pessoal procurei pelo forum mais nada funcionou gostaria de saber como mostra o valor de um var dentro de span?
Estou tentando

```
Var exemplo = 10;

Document.getElementById(pontos).innerHTML = Exemplo;

<span id="exemplo"></spam>
```

Mais n ta dando certo
Se alguem puder me explicar de forma simples estou comessando agr na linguagem

Comment: `document.getElementById("pontos").innerHTML = exemplo;` o javascript é case sensitive, cuidado com as maiusculas

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Vamos começar com os erros:

JavaScript é uma linguagem `case sensitive`, ou seja, a palavra reservada `var` não será interpretada como `Var`. O mesmo ocorre com o `Document` que deveria ser `document` e `Exemplo` que deveria ser `exemplo`, já que você declarou ele com o `D` minúsculo.

Todo código JavaScript dentro de um código HTML deve estar dentro da tag `<script></script>`.

Sabendo disso, converta seu código para este:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="exemplo"></span>

    <script>
      var exemplo = 10;

      document.getElementById('exemplo').innerHTML = exemplo;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```